# Yeoman composeWith only calling constructor in subgenerator

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to use `composeWith`, to call a subgenerator within the same generator package. Yet for some reason, only the constructor of the called generator is invoked.

My generator-package `generator-test` looks like this:

```
package.json
generators
-- app
  -- index.js
-- base
  -- index.js
```

My main generator in `app` looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
var yosay = require('yosay');

module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
    constructor: function () {
        console.log('constructing app');
        yeoman.generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    initializing: function() {
        console.log('initializing app');
        var done = this.async();
        this.composeWith('test:base',{ options: { } })
            .on('end', function() {
                done();
            });
    }
});
```

My subgenerator in `base`:

```
'use strict';
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
    constructor: function () {
        console.log('constructed base');
        yeoman.generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    initializing: function() {
        console.log('initialized base');
    }
});
```

This should generate 4 console outputs, yet I am only getting the first three:

```
constructing app
initializing app
constructed base
```

`initialized base` is never displayed. Why? Am I misunderstanding the concept of `composeWith`?

Or is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work because you cannot wait for the end on a composed generator.

Calling `this.async()` is pausing the run loop until the callback is called. In this case, it's never going to be called because the sub generator won't start running until the callback is called (but the callback wait for the sub generator to run). Basically, you're dead locking your node process.

Composition in Yeoman must be independent. It is very important generators stay decoupled. To enforce this, `yeoman-generator` don't offer flow control for composition other than the run loop priorities.

You'll need to rethink your code and decouple those generators.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So does this mean that first the initializing method of the main and then the sub generator is called, and only then the main generator continues? Or if I want this kind of functionality, would it be better to extend from a subgenerator instead of the base class?

Comment: The main generator methods will always run first in their own priority loop.

Comment: So all of them run first and only then the subgenerator is started?

Comment: If so, how can I have common tasks for multiple generators that run before the main generator?

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't care about the order stuff run in. If you care about the order, then you don't want composition.

Comment: That being said, you probably want composition any way. But you want to rethink your issue and come up with a solution that doesn't depend on the order stuff run in.

Comment: So you are telling me there is no way at all in yeoman to run checks that all dependencies (not just npm) are installed in every generator before you run the rest of the code? That doesn't make much sense...

Comment: I was just speaking about composed generators. Install methods are runned as part of the `install` priority. So the `end` priority will run after all install methods are done. You should learn more about the yeoman run loop over here: http://yeoman.io/authoring/running-context.html

Comment: Hm, so the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do is create an external vanilla javascript 'class' that takes care of the checks and then run those checks in the install method of all generators?